# Render multiple components based on length of view

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm creating movie reel app and my goal is to **render empty white squares** on each side of the "roll".

Just like this:

[image]

Now the length of my movie  roll is variable for each user, so I'd like to render the  squares based on the length of each users roll.

Here is some  example code:

The length of the `ReelsContainer` is 2000px tall.

```js
 <ReelsContainer>
          <ReelsLeft></ReelsLeft>
          <ReelsMiddle>
            <Image />
            <Image />
            <Image />
            <Image />
            <Image />
            <Image />
            <Image />
            <Image />
          </ReelsMiddle>
          <ReelsRight></ReelsRight>
        </ReelsContainer>
```

How do  I render  the white squares in both the `ReelsRight` and `ReelsLeft` components?

Comment: You might use pseudo-elements `after` and `before` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Answer (score 0):

```
<ReelsContainer>
  <ReelsLeft></ReelsLeft>
  <ReelsMiddle>
    {
      array.map(image, key) => <Image src={image} key={key} /> 
    }
    </ReelsMiddle>
  <ReelsRight></ReelsRight>
</ReelsContainer>
```